# Order by Case When ColumnName as Variable

Tags: sql, case

I've seen plenty of examples where people are using `CASE WHEN` in the `ORDER BY` clause of a `Select` statement. Typically, they're comparing the value of a variable to a string of the column name.

This is fine but what about when you have an extremely wide table?

Can you not just say something like

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @SortDesc = 1 THEN @SortField END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @SortDesc = 0 THEN @SortField END ASC
```

Or do you really really have to have a `CASE WHEN` for *every* column in the result set? Edit: Note that this is being converted from a SQL string to plain old SQL so dynamically building and executing it as a string isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can build up a dynamic sql string for something like this:

```
DECLARE @SortDesc varchar(max)
SELECT @SortDesc = [query to get your Sort column name].

DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ' + @SortDesc

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because I'm converting it FROM a sql string. So, not really a solution for me.

Comment: Ah ok. Might be helpful to add that detail to your question.

Comment: You know, I always manage to forget to add something that's kind of relevant. Thanks, it's been added.

Answer (score 0):

> Or do you really really have to have a CASE WHEN for every column in
>   the result set?
>       ORDER BY
>           CASE WHEN @SortDesc = 1 THEN @SortField END DESC,
>           CASE WHEN @SortDesc = 0 THEN @SortField END ASC

The point is that your shown code won't order. @SortField is replaced on all records by the same value, and you have no special order at all.

What you can do is address a @orderBy variable witch controls what realy ocurrs like this:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'NameDesc'     THEN name       END DESC,
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'NameAsc'      THEN name       END,
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'someDateDesc' THEN someDate   END DESC,
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'someDateAsc'  THEN someDate   END,
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'IdDesc'       THEN Id         END DESC,
CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'IdAsc'        THEN Id         END
```

Here you are ordering by six criterias, but five of them are null for all records, so your efecive order is by the selected field. And yes, you will need to write all variants that you want to use.

Comment: SortField is always just one column so it's okay, I just need to check whether it's ASC or DESC. But if what you say is correct, then I need to have a case for every column in the result set (which is what I want to avoid for obvious reasons)

Comment: if you have numeric fields, you can multiply by -1 on descendant case, but I dubt about performance and is not as clear as the shown way